# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field sCurrentOrderNumber

Tags: java, static, static-methods

I'm getting the following two errors when I attempt to run my java application - I would think I would simply change the values to static but that causes more issues.

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field sCurrentOrderNumber  Store_GUI.java  /Program 1/src/theCDstore   line 54 Java Problem
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method InitWindow() from the type Store_GUI    Store_GUI.java  /Program 1/src/theCDstore   line 55 Java Problem
```

Can someone explain how these can be resovled? When I attempt to change the methods to static I get MANY more errors besides these two:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field sStoreWindow Store_GUI.java  /Program 1/src/theCDstore   line 78 Java Problem
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field sStoreWindow Store_GUI.java  /Program 1/src/theCDstore   line 77 Java Problem
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field sPanel   Store_GUI.java  /Program 1/src/theCDstore   line 77 Java Problem
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method InitText() from the type Store_GUI  Store_GUI.java  /Program 1/src/theCDstore   line 73 Java Problem
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method InitPlacement() from the type Store_GUI Store_GUI.java  /Program 1/src/theCDstore   line 75 Java Problem
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method InitButtons() from the type Store_GUI   Store_GUI.java  /Program 1/src/theCDstore   line 69 Java Problem
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method InitLabels() from the type Store_GUI    Store_GUI.java  /Program 1/src/theCDstore   line 71 Java Problem
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field sPanel   Store_GUI.java  /Program 1/src/theCDstore   line 66 Java Problem
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field sStoreWindow Store_GUI.java  /Program 1/src/theCDstore   line 67 Java Problem
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field sStoreWindow Store_GUI.java  /Program 1/src/theCDstore   line 63 Java Problem
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field sPanel   Store_GUI.java  /Program 1/src/theCDstore   line 64 Java Problem
```

SOURCE SNIPPET:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;



public class Store_GUI {

    private  CDobject sCD;
    private  int sCurrentOrderNumber;
    private  JFrame sStoreWindow;
    private  JPanel sPanel;
    private  SpringLayout sLayout;
    private  Store_backend sStoreAction;

    private  JTextField sNumItemsTF;
    private  JTextField sIDTF;
    private  JTextField sQuantityTF;
    private  JTextField sItemInfoTF;
    private  JTextField sSubtotalTF;

    private  JLabel sNumItemsL;
    private  JLabel sIDL;
    private  JLabel sQuantityL;
    private  JLabel sItemInfoL;
    private  JLabel sSubtotalL;

    private  JButton sProcessItem;
    private  JButton sConfirmItem;
    private  JButton sViewOrder;
    private  JButton sFinishOrder;
    private  JButton sNewOrder;
    private  JButton sExit;

    /**
     * Starts the initialization of the JFrame, and initializes the StoreAction object.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Store_GUI().StartThread();
        sCurrentOrderNumber = 1;
        InitWindow();

    }

    /**
     * Sets many of the base attributes of the frame/panel and calls other methods to populate it.
     */
    private  void InitWindow(){
        sStoreWindow = new JFrame("Adrian's Wonderful World of Music");
        sPanel  = new JPanel();

        sPanel.setSize(1000, 300);
        sStoreWindow.setSize(1000, 300);

        InitButtons();

        InitLabels();

        InitText();

        InitPlacement();

        sStoreWindow.add(sPanel);
        sStoreWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
```

FULL SOURCE:

```
package theCDstore;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;



public class Store_GUI {

    private static CDobject sCD;
    private static int sCurrentOrderNumber;
    private static JFrame sStoreWindow;
    private static JPanel sPanel;
    private static SpringLayout sLayout;
    private static Store_backend sStoreAction;

    private static JTextField sNumItemsTF;
    private static JTextField sIDTF;
    private static JTextField sQuantityTF;
    private static JTextField sItemInfoTF;
    private static JTextField sSubtotalTF;

    private static JLabel sNumItemsL;
    private static JLabel sIDL;
    private static JLabel sQuantityL;
    private static JLabel sItemInfoL;
    private static JLabel sSubtotalL;

    private static JButton sProcessItem;
    private static JButton sConfirmItem;
    private static JButton sViewOrder;
    private static JButton sFinishOrder;
    private static JButton sNewOrder;
    private static JButton sExit;

    /**
     * Starts the initialization of the JFrame, and initializes the StoreAction object.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Store_GUI().StartThread();
        sCurrentOrderNumber = 1;
        InitWindow();

    }

    /**
     * Sets many of the base attributes of the frame/panel and calls other methods to populate it.
     */
    private static void InitWindow(){
        sStoreWindow = new JFrame("Adrian's Wonderful World of Music");
        sPanel  = new JPanel();

        sPanel.setSize(1000, 300);
        sStoreWindow.setSize(1000, 300);

        InitButtons();

        InitLabels();

        InitText();

        InitPlacement();

        sStoreWindow.add(sPanel);
        sStoreWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the JLabels and adds them to the panel.
     */
    private static void InitLabels(){
        sNumItemsL = new JLabel("Enter the number of items for this order:");
        sIDL = new JLabel("Enter CD ID for item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+":");
        sQuantityL = new JLabel("Enter quantity for item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+":");
        sItemInfoL = new JLabel("Item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+" info:");
        sSubtotalL = new JLabel("Order subtotal for "+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber-1)+" item(s):");

        sPanel.add(sNumItemsL);
        sPanel.add(sIDL);
        sPanel.add(sQuantityL);
        sPanel.add(sItemInfoL);
        sPanel.add(sSubtotalL);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the JTextFields and adds listeners to them.
     */
    private static void InitText(){
        sNumItemsTF = new JTextField(13);
        sIDTF = new JTextField(13);
        sQuantityTF = new JTextField(13);
        sItemInfoTF = new JTextField(40);
        sSubtotalTF = new JTextField(13);

        sIDTF.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
                if((arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) && !sIDTF.getText().isEmpty()){
                    sCD = sStoreAction.FindCD(Integer.valueOf(sIDTF.getText()));
                    if(!sQuantityTF.getText().isEmpty())
                        sStoreAction.SetCDInfo(sCD, Integer.valueOf(sQuantityTF.getText()));
                    else
                        sStoreAction.SetCDInfo(sCD, 1);
                    AutoComplete(sCD);
                }

            }});
        sIDTF.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                if(!sIDTF.getText().isEmpty()){
                    sCD = sStoreAction.FindCD(Integer.valueOf(sIDTF.getText()));

                    if(!sQuantityTF.getText().isEmpty())
                        sStoreAction.SetCDInfo(sCD, Integer.valueOf(sQuantityTF.getText()));
                    else
                        sStoreAction.SetCDInfo(sCD, 1);

                    AutoComplete(sCD);
                }
            }

        });
        sQuantityTF.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                if(!sQuantityTF.getText().isEmpty() && !sIDTF.getText().isEmpty()){
//                  sCD = sStoreAction.FindCD(Integer.valueOf(sIDTF.getText()),Integer.valueOf(sQuantityTF.getText()));
                    sCD = sStoreAction.FindCD(Integer.valueOf(sIDTF.getText()));

                    sStoreAction.SetCDInfo(sCD, Integer.valueOf(sQuantityTF.getText()));

                    AutoComplete(sCD);
                }

            }});
        sQuantityTF.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
                if(Character.isDigit(arg0.getKeyChar())){
//                  sCD = sStoreAction.FindCD(Integer.valueOf(sIDTF.getText()),Integer.valueOf(sQuantityTF.getText()));
                    sCD = sStoreAction.FindCD(Integer.valueOf(sIDTF.getText()));
                    sStoreAction.SetCDInfo(sCD, Integer.valueOf(sQuantityTF.getText()));

                    AutoComplete(sCD);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            }});

        sItemInfoTF.setEnabled(false);
        sSubtotalTF.setEditable(false);

        sPanel.add(sNumItemsTF);
        sPanel.add(sIDTF);
        sPanel.add(sQuantityTF);
        sPanel.add(sItemInfoTF);
        sPanel.add(sSubtotalTF);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the JButtons and adds listeners to them.
     */
    private static void InitButtons(){
        sProcessItem = new JButton("Process Item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+"");
        sConfirmItem = new JButton("Confirm Item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+"");
        sViewOrder = new JButton("View Order");
        sFinishOrder = new JButton("Finish Order");
        sNewOrder = new JButton("New Order");
        sExit = new JButton("Exit");

        sConfirmItem.setEnabled(false);
        sViewOrder.setEnabled(false);
        sFinishOrder.setEnabled(false);

        sProcessItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                sStoreAction.ProcessOrder(sCD, Integer.valueOf(sQuantityTF.getText()), Integer.valueOf(sNumItemsTF.getText()));
                if(sCurrentOrderNumber < Integer.valueOf(sNumItemsTF.getText())){
                    sNumItemsTF.setEditable(false);
                    sNumItemsTF.setEditable(false);
                    sConfirmItem.setEnabled(true);
                    sProcessItem.setEnabled(false);

                    sIDTF.setText("");
                    sQuantityTF.setText("");
                    sConfirmItem.setEnabled(false);
                    //sCurrentOrderNumber++;
                    RedrawLabels();
                }else{
                    sConfirmItem.setEnabled(false);
                    sProcessItem.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }});
        sConfirmItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(sPanel,"Item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+" accepted");
                sNumItemsTF.setEditable(false);
                sProcessItem.setEnabled(true);
                sConfirmItem.setEnabled(false);
            }});
        sViewOrder.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(sPanel, sStoreAction.getDisplayViewOrder());
            }});
        sFinishOrder.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(sPanel, sStoreAction.DisplayInvoice());
                sStoreAction.WriteInvoice();
                NewOrderClick();
            }});
        sNewOrder.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                NewOrderClick();
            }});
        sExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                sStoreWindow.dispose();
            }});

        sPanel.add(sProcessItem);
        sPanel.add(sConfirmItem);
        sPanel.add(sViewOrder);
        sPanel.add(sFinishOrder);
        sPanel.add(sNewOrder);
        sPanel.add(sExit);
    }

    /**
     * Positions all of the objects in the JPanel using SpringLayout.
     */
    private static void InitPlacement(){
        sLayout = new SpringLayout();
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,sNumItemsL, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH,sPanel);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,sNumItemsTF, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH,sPanel);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sNumItemsL, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, sPanel);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sNumItemsTF, 5, SpringLayout.EAST, sNumItemsL);

        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,sIDL, 7, SpringLayout.SOUTH,sNumItemsL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sIDL, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, sPanel);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sIDTF, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sNumItemsTF);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sIDTF, 5, SpringLayout.EAST, sIDL);

        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,sQuantityL, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH,sIDL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sQuantityL, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, sPanel);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sQuantityTF, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sIDTF);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sQuantityTF, 5, SpringLayout.EAST, sQuantityL);

        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,sItemInfoL, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH,sQuantityL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sItemInfoL, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, sPanel);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sItemInfoTF, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sQuantityTF);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sItemInfoTF, 5, SpringLayout.EAST, sItemInfoL);

        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,sSubtotalL, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH,sItemInfoL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sSubtotalL, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, sPanel);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sSubtotalTF, 5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sItemInfoTF);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sSubtotalTF, 5, SpringLayout.EAST, sSubtotalL);

        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sProcessItem, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sSubtotalL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sConfirmItem, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sSubtotalL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sViewOrder, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sSubtotalL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sFinishOrder, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sSubtotalL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sNewOrder, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sSubtotalL);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, sExit, 10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, sSubtotalL);

        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sProcessItem, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, sPanel);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sConfirmItem, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, sProcessItem);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sViewOrder, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, sConfirmItem);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sFinishOrder, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, sViewOrder);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sNewOrder, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, sFinishOrder);
        sLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, sExit, 10, SpringLayout.EAST, sNewOrder);

        sPanel.setLayout(sLayout);
    }

    /**
     * Auto fills the Info, Subtotal, and if necessary the Quantity text boxes.
     * @param mCD The current CD object.
     */
    private static void AutoComplete(CDobject mCD){
        sItemInfoTF.setText(mCD.getInfo());
        if(!sQuantityTF.getText().isEmpty())
            sSubtotalTF.setText(String.valueOf(sStoreAction.getDisplaySubtotal(mCD, Integer.valueOf(sQuantityTF.getText()))));
        else{
            sQuantityTF.setText("1");
            sSubtotalTF.setText(String.valueOf(sStoreAction.getDisplaySubtotal(mCD,1)));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the items number of many of the labels based on the sCurrentOrderNumber.
     */
    private static void RedrawLabels(){
        sProcessItem.setText("Process Item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+"");
        sConfirmItem.setText("Confirm Item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+"");
        sIDL.setText("Enter CD ID for item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+":");
        sQuantityL.setText("Enter quantity for item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+":");
        sItemInfoL.setText("Item #"+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber)+" info:");
        sSubtotalL.setText("Order subtotal for "+String.valueOf(sCurrentOrderNumber-1)+" item(s):");
    }

    /**
     * Clears the text fields, reinitializes the StoreAction object, and redraws the labels.
     */
    private static void NewOrderClick(){
        new Store_GUI().StartThread();
        sCurrentOrderNumber = 1;

        sIDTF.setText("");
        sQuantityTF.setText("");
        sItemInfoTF.setText("");
        sSubtotalTF.setText("");
        sNumItemsTF.setText("");

        RedrawLabels();

        sNumItemsTF.setEditable(true);
        sConfirmItem.setEnabled(true);
        sProcessItem.setEnabled(false);
    }


    /**
     * Defines a new class to execute the initialization of Store Action on its own thread.
     * @author david
     */
    class NewThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sStoreAction = new Store_backend();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts the thread.
     */
    private void StartThread(){
        new NewThread().start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this:

```
sCurrentOrderNumber = 1;
```

as `sCurrentOrderNumber` is an attribute field so you need to create an instance of `Store_GUI`  class and then set `sCurrentOrderNumber` value on that object.

You need to break these statements

```
    new Store_GUI().StartThread();
    sCurrentOrderNumber = 1;
```

to

```
Store_GUI storeGUIObj = new Store_GUI();
storeGUIObj.setSCurrentOrderNumber(1);
storeGUIObj.StartThread();
```

As you are missing a setter for your private filed sCurrentOrderNumber so you need to create one as mentioned above setSCurrentOrderNumber:

```
public void setSCurrentOrderNumber(int sCurrentOrderNumber )
{
    this.sCurrentOrderNumber = sCurrentOrderNumber ;
}
```